# What's the difference between "refer" and "recommend?"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

The question mainly concerns business where you would "refer/recommend someone to a new client." I wonder how similarly they can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring someone is simply directing a person's attention to another person without mentioning any qualifications.

Recommending someone is saying that the person has a good rating.